# Python module 'scm' has no attribute 'Open'

Tags: python, pyd

I have a third party pyd file called "scm.pyd". I have added this file and DLL file into PYTHONPATH.

import scm -> **works**
scm.Open() -> prints " module 'scm' has no attribute 'Open' " **error**.
I'm sure there's a function called Open(). When I use DLL version of scm with *ctypes* the Open() function works.
I want to use pyd file since function prototypes are ready to use and they have python syntax.
How to solve this?

Comment: `print(dir(scm))` to see what it has available

Comment: Check `scm.__file__` to make sure you are loading the correct `.pyd` file.  Check `dir(scm)` to make sure you are using the correct API (e.g. maybe it's actually `scm.scm.Open()` or something similar).

Comment: dir(scm) returns ['__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__']. What does it mean?

Comment: I realized I was working on wrong path. After the comments above, I realized that a light went out in my brain. Very thanks.

Comment: After going to the right path, i can acsess the methods.

Comment: After installing pycharm i call scm as import scm bu i get "ImportError: DLL load failed while importing scm:" despite i can acces command line terminal to the scm. Is there any special needing in pycharm?